# Html Checkboxes Are Not Giving Values To PHP

Tags: php

I am creating an html form that contains multiple checkboxes...
Here is my code

Form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="processstart.php" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <span class="label--input-group">Services you require</span>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap services">
      <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox check-group-input">
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Branding" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Branding</span>
          </label>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Design" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Design</span>
          </label>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Other" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Other</span>
          </label>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Development" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Development</span>
          </label>
        </span>
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Illustration" />&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Illustration</span>
          </label>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is processstart.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['services'])) {
    foreach($_POST['services'] as $services) {
      echo $services;
    }
  }
?>
```

Now nothing is getting echoed...I have tried var_dump(get_defined_vars()); and every other variable is defined except these checkboxes. Not even showing "null" there. What is going wrong?

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` and check if you can find `services` there.

Comment: Why are all the inputs named "services[]"

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></form>` add this and try

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger: not..still can't see services there...nothing

Comment: @RobertPeters That's called an input array, let's you store multiple values with same name

Comment: If you do not check checkboxes, they are sent to php as null. You cannnot see them. In order to see, check and post to php

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to close `<form>` tag and add submit button

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try i have action on same file but you can change action **values will be appear after any checkbox is checked else you can't get checkbox values**

On your form not any close `<form>` tag and not submit form action like button or `submit button`

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['services']))
{
    foreach($_POST['services'] as $services)
    {
        echo $services;
    }
}?>

<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">
<div class="form-row"><span class="label--input-group">Services you require</span><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap services"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox check-group-input"><span class="wpcf7-list-item">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Branding" />
            &nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Branding</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Design" />
            &nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Design</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Other" />
            &nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Other</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Development" />
            &nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Development</span></label>
          </span><span class="wpcf7-list-item">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Illustration" />
            &nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Illustration</span></label>
          </span></span></span></div>
          <input type="submit" name="sub">
          </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you are not submitting your form. You just specified in 'action'. To achieve your code workable, add a submit button. So that, while clicking it will call processstart.php

```
<input type="submit">
```